# How to use node-mysql correctly with Express.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm wondering how to use the module `node-mysql` correctly in Node.js (using Express.js). I have a main router with this:

```
var Post = require('./models/post.js');    

app.get('/archives', function (req, res) {
    Post.findArchives(function(posts, err) {
        if(err)
            res.send('404 Not found', 404);
        else
            res.render('archives', { posts: posts});
    });
});
```

And here's the content of the file `post.js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbURL = 'mysql://root@localhost/mydatabase';

exports.findArchives = function(callback) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbURL);
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts_view WHERE status != 0 ORDER BY date DESC', function(err, rows) {
        if(err) throw err
        callback(rows, err);
        connection.end();
    });
};
```

How can I improve it? Improve the error handling? Also, there's the function `handleDisconnect(connection);` on their Github (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) that I'm not really sure how to integrate to make sure that the application will not crash when the database is not responding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [mysql-simple](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-mysql-simple) library. It combines node-mysql with a pooling library to create a connection pool, and also includes the code to handle the disconnects.

If you want to make it super easy, you could just use that module.